# Determining longest time taken in boot process

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, performance

I'd like to find out what takes the most time in my boot process from GRUB to the Ubuntu login screen. How can I profile my boot process to find out what's taking so long?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never personally used it, but you could try `bootchart`. It is packaged for Ubuntu, as is a GUI for it, `pybootchartgui`.

Comment: Cool, so now that I've made a chart, how can I tell what's out of place?

Comment: @TKKocheran There's no magic method. The one-word answer is “experience”. Compare with a few other machines.

Comment: @TKKocheran: If you want to minimze boot time I suggest you disable all unwanted modules and also disable initrd and compile modules not off kernel.

Comment: @David, this of course, begs the question: of the over 50 modules in my kernel, how can I figure out which ones are needed and not needed? I have a fast 2.4-3.5GHz quad-core processor, a 7200RPM hybrid hard drive, and 8GB of RAM and I'm seeing boot take around 20-30 seconds. Also, what is initrd and how can I disable it? Compiling modules not off-kernel: meaning statically compiling the modules into the kernel?

Comment: @TKKocheran: Your are right off-kernel means statically into the kernel. You can use lspci -t or lspci -vvv to check your hardware. Initrd is a live file system and it's standard in Linux but I didn't needed it since many years. You can disable it even if you don't want to compile everything statically.

Comment: @TKKocheran: It's also easier when you frequently update the kernel. Compile time is a magnitude shorter. It's not so about speed but using a tight config helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootchart. It creates a profile of the boot process usually an image.

Answer (score 0):

An easy option for Ubuntu 15.04 and later is:

```
systemd-analyze blame
```